# Hide bottom table view when orientation changed to landscape mode in Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, orientation, nslayoutconstraint

I have one UIView and one UITableView sharing the screen with equal height in portrait mode.

Now how do I hide table view and fill entire screen with UIView when orientation is changed to landscape mode. and restore both UITableView and UIView in portrait mode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you implement `viewWillTransitionToSize` in your ViewController

```
var landscapeViewFrame = CGRect()
var landscapeTableViewFrame = CGRect()
var portraitViewFrame = CGRect()
var portraitTableViewFrame = CGRect()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    landscapeViewFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, view.frame.width / 2, view.frame.height)
    landscapeTableViewFrame = CGRectMake(view.frame.width, 0, view.frame.width / 2, self.view.frame.height);
    portraitViewFrame = view.bounds
    portraitTableViewFrame = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
}

override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    let isPortrait = (size.height > size.width);
    yourView.frame = isPortrait ? portraitViewFrame : landscapeViewFrame
    yourTableView.frame = isPortrait ? portraitTableViewFrame : landscapeTableViewFrame
    yourTableView.hidden = isPortrait
}
```

`viewWillTransitionToSize` notifies your viewController that the view frame is going to change. The `UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator` contains information about the animation, such as the duration / if animated at all.

**Update** now in swift. 
Basic idea: calculate the designated frames before. On device rotation change, the `viewWillTransitionToSize` is called and the frames for your views can be set. As mentioned before, you'll probably need animations to make everything look smooth

Comment: I want to hide UITableView  for landscape mode and show again the table view in Portrait mode as before. Please it will be more helpful if you can provide me with swift solution. Thanks anyway. @MarkHim

Comment: Replaced the code with more detailed swift code. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

1.first set device rotation in yourProject>General>device rotaion

2 write in your viewwillappear

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)`  name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification  object:nil];
```

3. write these method to what frame you want or which view you want to hide or unhide

   ```
   - (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
   {
       [self handleOrientation:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]];
   }


   - (void) handleOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation {

        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        {
            //handle the portrait view
        }
        else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        {
             //handle the landscape view
        }
   }
   ```

Comment: I already setup NSNotification center . All I want is solution to the [//handle portrait view] and [// handle the landscape view] parts in your solution. Thanks any way @jagveer